# linux show size of folder contents in ls or some other command

Tags: linux, command-line

I know these folders each have >80gb of files. Yet, they only show 4.0K in ls -lah? How can I have ls show size including the contents?

```
[root@aapsan01 aapxen01]# ls -lah
total 48K
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root 4.0K Sep 29 03:45 .
drwxrwxrwx 15 root root 4.0K Sep 27 09:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Sep 29 03:45 aapxen01.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Sep 28 12:10 aapxen01.1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Sep 27 09:21 aapxen01.2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Sep 27 09:21 aapxen01.3
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`du --max-depth=1 -h` should show how much space the folders use

Comment: That's what I want. Thanks. Too bad they couldn't make an ls switch to provide this info. O well.

Comment: I find that one pretty handy, so usually have it as an alias on my system like `du-dir` or something like that.

Comment: Actually adding `--max-depth=1` is kind of weird choice, because then sub-subfolders (and files inside those) are not counted at all. From question it's not clear whether that was wanted or not.

Comment: @Olli Subfolders are counted, but not displayed.

Comment: Also equivalent to `du -d 1 -h`

Comment: @checksum Since what version `du` has a `-d` option?

Comment: @A.Gille It's been quite some time I can't recall the version I used in my last comment. But so far it is available on my CentOS 7.6 and Ubuntu 18.04 distro.

Answer (score 13):

Using the command `du`:

```
du -sh .
```

Note that this takes some time, because it has to scan the directory contents.

Answer (score 6):

`du -sh`

where `s` displays a summary of the directory size.
`h` human readable format

Example:

```
[root@smsc tmp]# du -sh
219M    .
```

Answer (score 3):

`ls` shows the size of the directory entry, not of the directory contents. The directory itself is basically a list of all file names contained in the directory, and thus quite small.

For getting the combined size of a directory and its contents, use `du`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ du -sm * | sort -n | tail -n 20
6       persilleriet
10      reading-material
22      Desktop
24      android
24      workspace
28      Dropbox
35      skole
36      2011v
38      fpsu
42      archives
46      prosj
54      2011erm
54      books
64      svn
99      reference
227     tmp
311     muz
331     images
370     src
663     Downloads
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 'du'. [Further explanation](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/22.html)

Answer (score 1):

To show the size of `/var`, use:

```
du -sh /var
```

To show the size of *contents* of `/var`, use:

```
du -sh /var/*
```